# Neo4j Desktop - applications showing as "Not Installed"

Tags: neo4j

About 10 days ago I installed "Neo4j Desktop" on Windows.

Everything worked fine until yesterday when the "Neo4j Browser" application in the desktop app started showing as "Not Installed" (See [Screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EJ3g.jpg))

I can still run it in a web browser but I'd rather use the Neo4j Browser app.

I looked all over and couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Neo4j Desktop 1.1.7.

I have reinstalled it but didn't solve. Finally, from User Profile of Neo4j Desktop, signing out first and signing in again solved this issue in my case.

Comment: Thanks. I installed 1.1.7 (was previously on 1.1.6) but it didn't help.

I'm not logged in so your solution doesn't work for me. In fact, when I try to login it says I'm offline, even though I'm not.

Maybe this has something to do with the original problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have **Neo4j Desktop 1.1.8** on my mac and I had the same issue. The problem was that I enabled offline mode when I was on the airplane and at home the offline mode was still enabled and browser was shown as "not installed". So I **disabled the offline mode**, **restarted the desktop app** and now it is working properly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what "disabled the offline mode" means?

Comment: So if you go to the Neo4j Desktop -> Settings -> There is an "Offline mode" setting, which was enabled for me because I was working on a plane without internet and the program turned it on. And that caused the issue for me.